# Positional light shader code in OpenGL ES2.0?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, shader

Does anyone know of a good source for writing positional light code in OpenGL ES2?

All the tutorials I have seen expect your model to be at the world center (0,0,0), and the light is affecting that.

Although this might be useful in many cases, how about lights that can exist anywhere in the world? That is a lot more useful to me. :)

I am more looking for the shader code to implement this, but the current target platform is iOS with C++.

Answer (score 0):

I googled "fragment shader spot light" and got the [first page](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/spot-light-per-pixel/). It doesn't have a reflection effect but it does have positions and directions (you can use or throw out any).

Though I would suggest you to write your own shader depending on your specific needs and search web for effects you want as internet is overflowing with them.

Also you wrote that the model is in center and then applied that the light is in center. Anyway, to get the effect of light being elsewhere just use the uniform with light position and subtract that vector from the pixel position (describing the object position in light position coordinates) and use the result with the part of the shader relevant to light.